# How do I prove $f:[0,1]^3\rightarrow\mathbb R$ has a minimum and maximum?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How do I prove continuous function $f:[0,1]^3\rightarrow\mathbb R$ has a minimum and maximum?

Using compact, sequentially compact, continuous, or closed theorems.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous and so the image of $[0,1]^3$ is a compact, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$. What does such a subset look like?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $X=[0,1]^{3}$ for short and $\alpha=\sup\{f(x):x\in X\}$.

Choose a sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ so that $f(x_{n})\to \alpha$, and pass down to a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ by compactness of $X$ that converges to some $x\in X$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(x)=\lim f(x_{n_{k}})=\alpha$. Hence $f$ has a maximum in $X$. Similarly you show that $f$ has a minimum.

A slight detail which you may want to include is that $\alpha<\infty$. If, towards contradiction, you would assume that $\alpha=\infty$, then you could take a sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ with $f(x_{n})>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Take a converging subsequence and derive a contradiction.